# Incorrect source port (69) in request reply. TFTP sendFile

Tags: java, io, ftp, network-programming, tftp

I'm tring to execute this TFTP DOS send command by TFTP Client in Java:

```
tftp -i 192.168.1.13 put file1.romz file1.romz
```

It means to send the file file1.romz to host: 192.168.1.13, in binary way and rename the file when arrives to file1.romz. About [TFTP DOS command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff698993(v=ws.11).aspx).

This is the code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.apache.commons.net.tftp.TFTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.tftp.TFTPClient;

public class TFTPClientToSend {

public final static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean closed;
    int transferMode = TFTP.BINARY_MODE;
    String hostname, localFilename, remoteFilename;
    TFTPClient tftp;

    // Get host and file arguments
    hostname = "192.168.1.13";
    localFilename = "file1.romz";
    remoteFilename = "file1.romz";

    // Create our TFTP instance to handle the file transfer.
    tftp = new TFTPClient();

    // We want to timeout if a response takes longer than 60 seconds
    tftp.setDefaultTimeout(60000);

    // Open local socket
    try {
        tftp.open();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: could not open local UDP socket.");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // We haven't closed the local file yet.
    closed = false;

    // We're sending a file
    FileInputStream input = null;

    // Try to open local file for reading
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(localFilename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        tftp.close();
        System.err.println("Error: could not open local file for reading.");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Try to send local file via TFTP
    try {
        tftp.sendFile(remoteFilename, transferMode, input, hostname, 69);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: could not resolve hostname.");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(
                "Error: I/O exception occurred while sending file.");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        // Close local socket and input file
        tftp.close();
        try {
            input.close();
            closed = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            closed = false;
            System.err.println("Error: error closing file.");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    if (!closed) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

The fields are correct, but I get the following error message:

```
Error: I/O exception occurred while sending file.
Incorrect source port (69) in request reply.
```

The TFTP UDP port is officially 69. Windows Firewall is off and TFTP Lantronix Server is enable to update new firware by TFTP. Java uses a port randomly to send data in the first frame of the string. I think this is why I have this error message. How could you change that source port? Or is it another problem that causes this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Like a workaround. I've used this to execute a Windows DOS command in Java.

```
try {
    Process proceso = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tftp -i 192.168.1.13 put 
file1.romz file1.romz");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```